LEFT OUTER JOIN between a Temp table and a database table works like an INNER JOIN
I have a temp table (#) that has 30 rows of data, mainly date related data. It has the right data. It does not have an index or primary key.
I have a database table that has 22 rows. It has a primary key but not on the date column I am interested in.
I am LEFT OUTER JOINing the above two tables (temp table, database table - in this order) using a column with date datatype.
The result set, instead of 30 rows, shows only 22 rows!
Where am I in error?
SELECT        
    eps.EmployeeName,
    eps.JobName,
    eps.Department,
    CONVERT(date,eps.WorkDate) AS WorkDate,
    a.*
FROM #TEMP_table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        x.*,
        pac.JobName,
        pac.Department
    FROM DatabaseTable x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees pac
        ON x.EmployeeId = pac.EmployeeId
) eps
    ON a.ThirtyCalendarDays = CONVERT(date,eps.WorkDate)

ThirtyCalendarDays has 30 consecutive calendar days that need not be in the same month. #TEMP_table1 has been developed after a lot of data manipulation.
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_table1
(
    ListofDatePoints date,
    StartDateRange date,
    EndDateRange date,
    ThirtyCalendarDays date,
    Comment nvarchar(25)
);

INSERT INTO #TEMP_table1
VALUES
('2024-10-31',  '2024-10-02',   '2024-10-31',   '2024-10-02',   NULL),
('2024-10-31',  '2024-10-02',   '2024-10-31',   '2024-10-03',   NULL),
('2024-10-31',  '2024-10-02',   '2024-10-31',   '2024-10-04',   NULL),
('2024-10-31',  '2024-10-02',   '2024-10-31',   '2024-10-05',   'Weekend'),
('2024-10-31',  '2024-10-02',   '2024-10-31',   '2024-10-06',   'Weekend')

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_table1

CREATE TABLE DatabaseTableTestDemo
(
    EmployeeId int,
    WorkDate date,
    JobName varchar (20)
);

INSERT INTO DatabaseTableTestDemo
VALUES
(1, '2024-10-04',   'Driver'),
(2, '2024-10-05',   'Conductor')

SELECT * FROM DatabaseTableTestDemo

SELECT
    eps.EmployeeId,
    eps.JobName,
    CONVERT(date,eps.WorkDate) AS WorkDate,
    a.*
FROM #TEMP_table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN DatabaseTableTestDemo eps
    ON a.ThirtyCalendarDays = eps.WorkDate

I am getting 5 rows, as expected but in my actual database I am getting only 2 rows.

Without a reproducable script, your question becomes something like: `how can left join remove rows", which it doesn't, so what can anyone here do to help you? It's obvious you have a bug somewhere, so why not look for it

@user3812887 you need to explain why the linked duplicate doesn't help you...

A reproducable script is a script anyone can run which displays incorrect behaviour, does your script do that?

Haha... ops that script works correctly... in that case yes, we can't help if we can't reproduce it.

Without a [mre], no @user3812887 .

Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization & input; desired & actual output including verbatim error messages; tags & versions;
specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code you show is OK extended by code you show is not OK.
(Debug fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including
constraints & indexes). [ask] [Help]
Chop at the 1st expression with unexpected result & say what you
expected & why you expect it, justified by authoritative
documentation. (Debug fundamental.)

Clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments.
